# Remove dark background around clipped image in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, clip

I used QGIS 3 for clipping a satellite image using a shapefile.  The output raster gave a clipped image with dark background. How to fix this issue?

[image: Clipped image with dark background]

Comment: Repeat the clipping process and enter a value of -9999 under NoData value field and it should be solved. Check the comments: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336461/using-clip-by-mask-on-qgis

Comment: Add the dark value as `Additional no data value` here : https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#transparency-properties